# Orientdb get last vertex from each path when Traversing by edge property

Tags: orientdb

I need to traverse all vertices that are connected by edges where the property 'dependence' is 'true'

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
FROM (TRAVERSE * 
      FROM (SELECT outE() FROM 9:5) 
      WHILE (@class = 'E' AND dependence = 'yes') OR @class = 'V')
WHERE @class = 'V'
```

Although im not sure if is the best way to do it, this seems to work fine following only the paths where edges have *'dependence' = 'yes'*.

Now, There could be more than one path generated, and I need to get the last vertex from each path/branch.

***traverserdVertex(-1)*** should return the last one, but im guessing that is from the whole traversal so is no good. (and it looks like there's a bug because it retrieves more than one)

The outer *SELECT* returns the whole bag of vertices so I'm thinking that maybe finding the ones that doesn't have an outgoing edge with *dependence='yes'* might solve it, although I'm not sure how to do it nicely.

**SOLUTION:**

```
SELECT
    FROM (TRAVERSE * 
          FROM (SELECT outE() FROM 9:5) 
          WHILE (@class = 'E' AND dependence = 'yes') OR @class = 'V')
    WHERE @class = 'V' AND NOT (outE() contains (dependence='yes'))
```

This effectively returns the last vertex from each branch. I'm open to any other option, I'm wondering if it could be improved.

Comment: I think you could write your own function in Javascript under OrientDB Server function and then call it from SQL. I try to write it.

Comment: i have just found a solution, but im curious about your approach, ill wait for it to see the javascript alternatve :) thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I tried with an example by building the following graph

[image]

The javascript function "myFunction" has three parameters which are ridVertex, property and value

```
var g=orient.getGraph();
var previous=[];
var currently=[];
var node=[];
var b=g.command("sql","select from v where @rid =" + ridVertex);
if(b.length>0){
   previous.push(b[0]);
   node.push(b[0]);
   do{
      for(i=0;i<previous.length;i++){
         var edges=g.command("sql","select expand(outE()) from V   where @rid = "+ previous[i].getId());
         var myVertex=[];   
         for(j=0;j<edges.length;j++){ 
            var edge=edges[j];
            var dependence=edge.getProperty(property);
            if(dependence==value){
               var vIn=edge.getProperty("in");
               myVertex.push(vIn);
            }
          }
          if(myVertex.length>0){
             setPaths();
          }
       }
       change();
    }while(previous.length>0);  
}
return node;

function setPaths(){
   for (m = 0; m < node.length; m++) {
      var lastId=node[m].getId().toString();
      var idOut=previous[i].getId().toString();
      if (lastId==idOut) {
         for(r=0;r<myVertex.length;r++){
            var vertex=myVertex[r];
            node.push(vertex);
            currently.push(vertex);
        }
        node.splice(m,1);
        break;
      }
   }
}

function change(){
    previous=[];
    for (indice=0;indice<currently.length;indice++)
        previous.push(currently[indice]);
    currently=[];
}
```

Using the following command

```
select expand(result) from (select myFunction("#9:0","dependence","yes") as result)
```

the paths are A -> D and A -> B -> C -> G and then will be returned the verteces D and G

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Thats interesting, I didnt know you could do that, although it looks way to verbose to me. I Think the OSql statement above solves it with better performance, but still is an interesting thing to have in mind, injecting javascript code. nice :)

Answer (score 0):

The following is a slight simplification of @sebastian's solution, using Allesandro's graph (with dependentOn.value being 0 or 1):

```
select from
  (TRAVERSE * FROM (select from Circle where name="A")
   while (@CLASS="dependentOn" and value=1) OR @CLASS="Circle")
where @CLASS='Circle' AND NOT (outE().value contains 1)

----+-----+------+----+--------------
#   |@RID |@CLASS|name|in_dependentOn
----+-----+------+----+--------------
0   |#11:6|Circle|G   |[#12:4]       
1   |#11:3|Circle|D   |[#12:1]
```