# Traversing based on multiple vertexes

Tags: graph, orientdb, graph-traversal

I've a graph in OrientDB with vertexes `Area` & `Place` with edges `visited`. Your average path goes `Area > visited > Place > visited > Place > visited > Place > visited > Place` and so on. It tracks which places user visited after the previous one. `visited` contains YYYYmmDD `datestamp`.

I'm trying to find out all `Area` vertexes based on arbitrary `Place` vertexes for certain day - i.e. I want to know from which areas users came to a certain place after visiting certain place first.

Traversing from any single `Place` in the path would be easy but I need to to follow the path for only for a specific `datestamp`. What I did was that I created index for `datestamp` to get day's `visited` edges quickly and then finds the one that has `in` to the first `Place`. However now I can't figure out how to create a fast query that finds all `Area` vertexes based on the first `Place` while also making sure that the path contains second `Place` as well. I can get path between first and second `Place` via `shortestPath()` but I still have the same problem with extending the path to include `Area` vertexes.

I found some theory on the subject but if somebody could point me to the right direction how to use OrientDB to do this instead of pure graph theory I would really appreciate it - I've been working on this for the past week now. Originally this was done via bruteforce by traversing everything and then selecting but as the database grows it's not obviously sustainable.

Comment: Can you add the screen of the schema? Can you explain it better please?

Comment: Can you be more specific what you don't understand about the schema? It's all in the first paragraph and honestly I'm not sure how to explain it any better without knowing what's not clear. It's 2 vertexes Area and Place, and visited edge that connects Area to Place and Place to Place.

Comment: what does Place contain? A reference to user? The timestamp itself? Or is the timestamp on edges?

Comment: Place is a static record of a place like for example Bob's Hamburger Joint. Area is a static record for a geographic area like Bronx, NY. Timestamp exists only in the edges and are created with user visits Places. User reference is also in the edges but I didn't want to bring it up here because in this case we are aggregating over all paths regardless of the user to produce list of Areas based on arbitrary Places.

Answer (score 0):

Edit

Try this JavaScript function that has three parameters(places,date,propertyPlace)

```
var g=orient.getGraph();
var myPlaces=places.substring(1,places.length-1).split(",");
var b=g.command("sql","select from Area");
var result=[];
if(checkPlaces){
    for(i=0;i<b.length;i++){
        var listPlaces=[];
        for(ind=0;ind<myPlaces.length;ind++){
            listPlaces.push(myPlaces[ind]);
        }
        if(search(b[i],listPlaces)){
            result.push(b[i]);
        }
    }
}
return result;

function checkPlaces() {
    for(index=0;index<myPlaces.length;index++){
        var place=g.command("sql","select from Place where "+ propertyPlace + "='"+myPlaces[index]+"'");
        if(place.length==0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function checkDate(edge){
  var datestamp=edge.getRecord().field("datestamp");
  var year=datestamp.getYear()+1900;
  var month=datestamp.getMonth()+1;
  var day=datestamp.getDate();
  var app=date.split("-");
  var myYear=parseInt(app[0]);
  var myMonth=parseInt(app[1]);
  var myDay=parseInt(app[2]);
  if(year==myYear && month==myMonth && day==myDay){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}


function search(v,places){
    var edge=v.getRecord().field("out_visited"); 
    if(edge!=null){
        var edgeIterator=edge.iterator();
        while(edgeIterator.hasNext()){
            var edge = edgeIterator.next();
            if (checkDate(edge)) {
                var v1 = edge.field("in");
                if(v1!=null){
                    var name = v1.field(propertyPlace);
                    for(j=0;j<places.length;j++){
                        if(name==(places[j])) {
                            places.splice(j, 1);
                            break;
                        }   
                    }
                    if(places.length==0){ 
                        return true;
                    }
                    else if(search(v1,places)){
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Using the following command

```
select expand(result) from (select myFunction("[place1,place2]","2015-12-03","name") as result)
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Yes, exactly like that. However the problem is a bit more complicated. Sometimes I've multiple places as requirements and I need to get only areas where those places are in the path. For example if I had `place1` and `place2` as place requirements, and timestamp "2015-12-03" I should only get `area1`.

Comment: Place 2 and place 1 must be visited consecutively, or not

Answer (score 0):

I created the three Vertices 'Area', 'Place' and 'User' and the two Edges 'visited' and 'placed' where datestamp is a property on the edge 'visited.
In this way you don't have to insert everytime the User as a property on the edge.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution to this exact problem but instead a workaround I came up with. Inspired by [Orientdb get last vertex from each path when Traversing by edge property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33903845/orientdb-get-last-vertex-from-each-path-when-traversing-by-edge-property)

I changed to structure so that `Area` is now created per visitation instead of being static and it includes yyyymmdd timestamp also. Now I can use `Area` to start the query and use `visited` edges to get `Place` vertices only for a certain date.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT $path, $depth FROM (
    TRAVERSE * FROM (
        SELECT outE('visited') FROM (
            SELECT EXPAND(rid) FROM INDEX:area.dt WHERE key = 20151205
        )
    ) WHILE (@class = 'visited' AND dt = 20151205) OR @class = 'place') 
WHERE @class = 'place' AND NOT (outE() contains (dt=20151205))
```

This returns correct paths with vertices and edges so you can verify it's only for a certain day. However note that `Area` is not contained in the path and I still need to figure out how to do that but if you want, you can just traverse the first `visited` edge backwards in the path and get it that way.